# HIVE-JOIN ON clause with complex right operand fails

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am using HIVE 1.2

TABLE t1:- date_col with DATE datatype
TABLE t2:- date_col with DATE datatype

```
SELECT * from t1 inner join t2 ON 
t1.date_col = CAST(DATE_FORMAT(t2.date_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS TIMESTAMP) 
- INTERVAL '2 01:30:00' DAY TO SECOND
```

This kind of a query fails with the exception :

```
FAILED: SemanticException '2 01:30:00' encountered with 0 children
```

But when the same ON clause condition is used in WHERE clause it works fine.
Can anybody point out what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: HIVE may not to treating it as a complete expression.Try to add one more bracket around cast function.   (CAST(DATE_FORMAT(t2.date_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS TIMESTAMP) 
- INTERVAL '2 01:30:00' DAY TO SECOND)

Comment: That is the first thing I tried :) ... but to no avail :-/

Comment: did you try changing that to subqueries and creating a column with your complex operand?